# Universal Angular 4: getting SyntaxError while using ng2 nouislider

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am working on Universal Angular 4 project.
while adding **"nouislider"** in html file,i am getting the following error

```
import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>       at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/user/Desktop//node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:384:14)
>       at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

slider is working fine when i am working on angular 4 only i.e without server side rendering(SSR) but getting above error when doing SSR.
  Please help me to get out of this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using babel? node.js (as is) not supporting ths es6 `import` statement.

Comment: yes,i am using babel to transpile from es6 to commonjs.

Comment: It is likely they are using DOM manipulations within the library.

Comment: Are you using webpack? If so, you can whitelist imports

Comment: Thanks @David...your suggestion worked.